# How to cancel or delete after seen UILocalNotification in swift3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uilocalnotification

I used the following code in my project, but can't delete notification.

```
UIApplication.shared.cancelAllLocalNotifications()
```

How to solve this problem? Have anyone this problem? Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Along with

```
UIApplication.shared.cancelAllLocalNotifications()
```

Try this also

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

I think it will delete all notifications from your notification center panel. Try that out.

As `UIApplication.shared.cancelAllLocalNotifications()` only cancels the delivery of all scheduled local notifications and doesn't delete the notification.